# Relating Models across Databases in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I'm working with Databases that I cannot alter. I three tables, 2 of which are in a different database than the main table.

```
Voucher - Main Table
CustKey FiscPer FiscYear etc.
1884     6      2011

FiscPer is the Month Number.



LU_MONTH - Table 1 in different DB

MONTH_ID MONTH_OF_YEAR YEAR_ID
200806   2011            6



FACT_DATA - Table 2 in different DB

SCHOOLKEY MONTH_ID
1884       200806
```

I am trying to make them relate in Cakephp. The tables are not set up in the way CakePHP wants them. I am trying to make the Voucher Model grab the information in FACT_DATA using LU_MONTH as the middle join table. Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look through the [CakePHP book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/contents.html) - specifically the part on [Model Attributes](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html), you'll likely find what you want - `useDbConfig`, `useTable` ...etc

Comment: Yes I have all of that setup. I can get each individual table as a Model but I can't relate them easily.